# Missing closing brace in SFML program?

Tags: visual-c++, sfml

I made a program using C++ and SFML. The program is supposed to generate 20 circles that are either red or blue, and it did work. Yet, I made a few changes, saved, and came back to it on VS a few hours later to find that I keep getting an error:

'{': No matching token found (Line 9)

I keep scanning through the code and I can't seem to find the issue at all.

Code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{ //Line 9
    unsigned seed = chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    default_random_engine generator(seed);
    uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution1(0, 1024);
    uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution2(1, 2);

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1024, 1024), "Spooky Circle Box");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
    shape.setPosition(10, 10);

    std::vector<sf::CircleShape> circles(20);

    window.clear();

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++) {
        int find = 0;
        int find_color = 0;
        while (find != 20) {
            circles[i].setPosition(distribution1(generator), distribution1(generator));
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < circles.size(); j++) {
                if (i == j || (circles[i].getPosition().x != circles[j].getPosition().x || circles[i].getPosition().y != circles[j].getPosition().y)) {
                    find++;
                } else;
            if (find != 20) {
                find = 0;
            } else;
        }
        find = 0;
        find_color = distribution2(generator);
        circles[i].setRadius(5.f);

        if (find_color == 1) {
            circles[i].setFillColor(sf::Color::Blue);
        } else { circles[i].setFillColor(sf::Color::Red); }

        window.draw(circles[i]);
    }

    window.display();

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::sleep((sf::milliseconds(100)));
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket at the end, but you should re-check all your braces and ensure you're closing them in the right place. I think you have some bad indentation somewhere

Comment: Said that, your code is quite messy, you have at least two (unintended) infinite loops. First one unables you to scape from `while(find != 20)`, because you're setting `find` to 0 each time inside the second `for`. Second "infinite" loop would be  `while(window.isOpen())` because, as it name says, you'll be there until your window closes

Comment: I know I'm missing a brace somewhere, but I don't see the issue, and that's my problem. Also, those are both supposed to be infinite loops. The first one goes until it finds a position that works, and that only takes 1-3 tries. The second one is supposed to be that way, otherwise you'd never be able to close the window properly. I suppose I could add a pause to lower strain.

Comment: If your intention is just to draw circles once, I think you're missing that closing brace just between lines 32 and 33. It seems you're indenting the code, but that `for` (line 29) needs the brace

Answer (score 1):

I explain further my comments, but I'm not going to post any *repaired* code. I only suggest a way of doing things.

By the structure of you're code, it seems you're trying to generate some blue or red circles randomly distributed over the window, but, at the same time, you're trying to draw them.

You should differentiate your actual data from your drawing stuff. My suggested pseudo-code would be.

```
int main(){int main(){
    // 1 . Declare your circle vector

    // 2 . Populate that vector with random circles (random position, random color)

    // Now draw those circles
    // 3 . while(window.isOpen()) loop

        // 3.1 Clear the window

        // 3.2 Draw your circles

        // 3.3 Display the stuff

}
```

That point 3 it's basically the way to draw stuff acording [SFML tutorials](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/window-window.php#bringing-the-window-to-life).

Comment: That's what I did, except for number 3. I know the first SFML example has the shapes being drawn in the isOpen loop, but that's really stupid. Not only is it wrong, it's tricking new people into thinking it's okay. If you make it clear, draw, and display inside the loop, it'll draw the shape(s) as many times as it can in the shortest amount of time. Running the example, which just draws a low res circle, caused the program to suck up 30% of my CPU usage. Moving the draw out of the loop or adding a pause lowered that to 0%.

Comment: Oh, and I'm not generating the circles and drawing them at the same time. I'm generating them once, and then drawing them once after they're all generated. Not trying to be rude, but you shouldn't be trying to answer if you don't know SFML.

Comment: @Anoraki If you don't *clear-draw-display* each time you won't be able to draw moving stuff. If you (i'm not sure if that's your case) want to move your circles, you'll be forced to clear and redraw each time.